# ng-bootstrap popover not showing

Tags: angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

my ng-bootstrap popover is not showing on hover. I have imported NgbModule in anangular.

When I hover over the popover it is appending itself to the body, however, display is set so none. It uses the following css.

```
.popover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1060;
    display: none;
    max-width: 276px;
    padding: 1px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: left;
    text-align: start;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    line-break: auto;
}
```

I have included bootstrap in webpack like this:

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css']
```

But it is not showing up.

I tried to include bootstrap also in my index.html and the popover does not show up.

Please help I need to finish this project by next week.

Comment: Works for me perfectly fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/F6WiVfZPKwiX0O2bJIiL?p=preview. Can you try to reproduce your problem in plunker? What is a version of Bootstrap CSS and ng-bootstrap that you are using? Please note that ng-bootstrap beta _requires_ Bootstrap CSS 4.beta.

Comment: It is not so easy to reproduce as I am using dotnet core with webpack, not using angular cli.
I had `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.30"` and
`"bootstrap": "^3.3.7"`

Comment: Once again, ng-bootstrap beta requires Bootstrap CSS 4.beta. It will _not_ work properly with `"bootstrap": "^3.3.7"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using **Bootstrap 4 or 3**, you can simply override the default **css** of the `ngb-popover-window` tag and set the **css** `display` property to `block !important` in the file `style.css` like this:

```
 ngb-popover-window {
     position: absolute;
     width: auto !important;
     display: block !important;
     background-color: #fafafa !important;
     border: 1px solid #fafafa !important;
     max-width: none !important;
 }
```